# Using MediaEnded in Javascript to launch a new Web page

Tags: javascript

How do I use the MediaEnded event in Javascript to detect the end of a playing video (QuickTime) and use that event to open a new web page?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 makes this quite simple:

```
document.getElementById('your_video').onended = function() {
  newWindow = window.open(url, 'Foo', 'height=250,width = 200');

  if (window.focus) {newWindow.focus()}
}
```